# How to implement AES Encrypting for ESP8266 implemented on Hardware?

Tags: microcontroller, esp8266, encryption, nodemcu, aes

I need to write a basic encryption program for ESP8266. I did read the datasheet (https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf), and them says that existis the methods of encrypt: WEP/TKIP/AES. My main question is: The AES method, is implemented on software or hardware? This module is very simple, (36KB RAM, 90MHz CPU clock), so the algorithm is heavy to process. If AES is implemented in hardware, I think this task gets simpler, but I don't know how to use this. I did read at web, and the examples uses a #include "AES.h" lib, I don't know if this is implemented on hardware or software. The site of ESP8266 don't reply this question. So, I wants know about this and how, or where I found help, to implement this.

Ps.: I don't want use Arduino.

Also, I've already use this, https://github.com/CHERTS/esp8266-devkit/tree/master/Espressif/examples/ESP8266. But, for little jobs.

Comment: There are some "[mini AES](https://github.com/armandooj/Mini-AES)" implementations on Github.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if you're familiar with FPGAs, but they're used in hardware dedicated bitcoin mining boxes and contain arrays of gates and latches in which you can use C code, VHDL or schematics to implement algorithms in hardware.

https://www.design-reuse.com/articles/13981/fpga-implementation-of-aes-encryption-and-decryption.html

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications, but what does this have to do my question?

Comment: You:  "If AES is implemented in hardware, I think this task gets simpler, but I don't know how to use this."

Me: "you can use C code, VHDL or schematics to implement algorithms in hardware."

I'm not sure how I can be more clear.

The title of the article is "FPGA Implementation of AES encryption".  How is this not relevant to your question?